# Como remover caracteres de posição específica de uma string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, caracteres

Tenho uma string lida de um arquivo que contém um dado e o caractere especial de nova linha '\n'.
Exemplo:

```
dado = 'teste \n'
```

Primeiro verifico o tamanho da string, então posso remover os dois ultimos caracteres, mas como posso remover apontando a posição específica do caractere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings em Python, como em várias outras linguagens, não são mutáveis: isso é, para qualquer modificação, voce deve criar uma nova string (em geral é ok associar a nova string a mesma variável).

Agora, a sintaxe de "fatias" (slices)  do Python é extremamente conveniente para recortar, e colar strings - é só ter em mente que, como se fosse uma regua, o primeiro indice da fatia, antes do ":" é inclusivo, e o final é exclusivo - isso permite coisas bem práticas do tipo:

```
dado = dado [0:4]  + dado[4:]
```

Preserva a mesma string sem duplicar nenhuma letra. (Corta do começo até a posição 4 - o 0 poderia ser omitido e depois corta da posição 4 até o final - o final omitido permite que não se precise saber o tamanho total da string)

Assim, para cortar a letra da posição [4] (no caso, o segundo "e"), você possa escrever:

```
dado = dado[0:3] + dado[4:]
```

A sintaxe de índices e fatias também permite índices negativos - que contam a partir do final da string. Assim, vazio  é o final da string, "-1" é o endereço do último caractere, "-2" do penúltimo, e assim por diante.

Para cortar os dois últimos caracteres, basta fazer:

```
dado = dado[:-2]
```

(corte do começo até a posição do penúltimo caractere)
Dificilmente você vai ter um caso desses em que precise colocar explicitamente o tamanho da string (retornado por `len(dado)`) -  e isso evita uma porção de código que - na cabeça da gente é "direto", mas ficar digitando, e olhando no código seria bem mais cansativo do que simplesmente usar indices negativos.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso, você pode utilizar os [slices](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/).

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
dado = dado[:5] # Pega do começo até a posição 5 - 1
```

Lembrando que as *strings* são objetos [imutáveis](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/), assim, não é possível remover um caractere: O que você pode fazer, na verdade, atribuir novamente à sua variável uma cópia da *string* sem os caracteres indesejados.